# R all combinations of dafaframe based on ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am struggling with the following problem here: 
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  aa<-c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
  bb<-c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
  cc<-c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0)

  d<-data.frame(aa,bb,cc)
```

The data is always binary and codes for absence/presence data.
What I would like to have are new columns with all possible combinations of the variables meeting certain assumptions. For this dataframe it would be like

```
d$aabb<-ifelse(d$aa=="1"&d$bb=="1"&d$cc=="0",1,0) #aa=1,bb=1,cc=0
d$aacc<-ifelse(d$aa=="1"&d$cc=="1"&d$bb=="0",1,0) #aa=1,bb=0,cc=1
d$bbcc<-ifelse(d$bb=="1"&d$cc=="1"&d$aa=="0",1,0) #aa=0,bb=1,cc=0
d$daabbcc<-ifelse(d$aa=="1"&d$bb=="1"&d$cc=="1",1,0) #aa=bb==cc=1
```

However, I have 30 Columns and I dont want to fill them all out by hand. Another nice thing would be if the resulting column names are a combination of the original ones `(aa+bb->aabb)`, etc.

I looked at the `expand.grid()` function but this was not what I was looking for
Thanks in advance

Comment: Am i right in thinking you want a variable when all 30 are 1, 29 are 1, 28 are 1 etc. So you want something like `sapply(2:30, function(n)choose(30,n))` columns?

Comment: If you have 30 columns to start with, you're going to end up with 2^30 ~ 1 billion columns after taking all combinations. You should rethink your problem to see if it's really necessary to do this. At the least, you should list what assumptions have to be met regarding those combinations.

Comment: Ok, you are right. 30 columns is to much. I reduced the dataset to 6 variables. But how do I get the ifelse statement into sapply?

Comment: I fully agree to @HongOoi and suspect that you are a victim of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-) You should ask about the ultimate goal you actually want to do. Instead you make the mistake of asking how to finish the solution which you have in mind, leaving no opportunity for us to find better solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some data:

```
aa<-c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
bb<-c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
cc<-c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
dd<-rbinom(7,1,.5)
ee<-rbinom(7,1,.5)
ff<-rbinom(7,1,.5)
d<-data.frame(aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff)
```

Create a variable that is all possible combinations of the values:

```
combinations <- apply(d,1,function(x) paste(names(d)[as.logical(x)],collapse=""))
```

Convert that variable into a set of named variables and bind the results to `d`:

```
d2 <- sapply(unique(combinations), function(x) as.numeric(combinations==x))
```

Prevent duplicated column names when only one value is present in the original df:

```
colnames(d2) <- paste0(colnames(d2),"1") # could be any naming convention
d2 <- cbind(d, d2)
```

Comment: +1 I'm not so sure about using `assign` inside an `sapply` like that (maybe it's fine), but this gets the job done nicely. Good stuff.

Comment: I don't think this does the job. What OP is after is a 2^6 = 64-column dataset, containing all possible combinations of `aa` through `ff`. Each of these columns is the result of ANDing the starting columns that make up that particular combination.

Comment: 2^6 - 1 as presumably d$NULL isnt required

Comment: Well, OP is unclear about whether he needs all possible combinations or only all present combinations. My intuition was the latter.

Comment: @SimonO101 I updated; it seems `assign` wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much, this was what I was looking for. Works very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of its applicability to an actual problem, this was kind of an interesting programming exercise. Here's code to create all 63 (=2^6 - 1) possible combinations from 6 columns, excluding the null. (As an aside, I don't see what's unclear about the question; it says "all possible combinations" in the second sentence, and one of the variables created in the sample code is all zeros (`d$aabbcc`.))

```
# create the source data
d <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(60, 1, 0.5), ncol=6))
names(d) <- letters[1:6]


# generate matrix of all possible combinations (except the null)
v <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(c(FALSE, TRUE)), ncol(d))))[-1, ]

# convert the matrix into a list of column indexes
indexes <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(v)), function(x) v[x, ])
names(indexes) <- apply(v, 1, function(x) paste(names(d)[x], collapse="."))

# compute values from the source data
out <- data.frame(lapply(indexes, function(i) as.numeric(apply(d[i], 1, all))))
```

There's some unnecessary computations going on, most obviously in how later combinations don't reuse the values from earlier ones. Still, this takes a fraction of a second even with 1000 rows, and only a few seconds with 100000 rows. Seeing as the problem is only feasible for a small number of columns, I didn't think further optimisation was worth the trouble.

Comment: +1 Both for actually going to the effort to do this and a surprisingly (at least to me) short block of code to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

#### A possible solution using the *[sets](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/index.html)* package...

Setup as given:

```
aa <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
bb <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
cc <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

d <- data.frame(aa, bb, cc)
```

And prep environment...

```
require(sets, quietly = T)
require(data.table, quietly = T)
```

Create a unique listing of names in 'set' order by creating a set of sets from `d`.

```
# Created as a list so that duplicates are kept.
namesets <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(d)), function(i) {
    gset(colnames(d), memberships = d[i, ])
})

# Then combine the set memberships into names and assign to the sets.
setnames <- sapply(namesets, function(s) {
    ifelse(set_is_empty(s), "none", paste(as.character(s), collapse = ""))
})
names(namesets) <- setnames

# Creating set of sets from namesets orders the names and removes duplicates.
namesets <- as.set(namesets)

print(namesets)

## {none = {}, aa = {"aa"}, bb = {"bb"}, cc = {"cc"}, aabb = {"aa",
##  "bb"}, bbcc = {"bb", "cc"}}

# Making it easy to create an ordered listing that we can use as a key.
setnames <- ordered(setnames, levels = names(namesets))
print(setnames)

## [1] bb   bbcc none aa   aabb cc   bb  
## Levels: none < aa < bb < cc < aabb < bbcc
```

Converting `d` into a data.table we can then populate member-set columns in various ways...

```
# First a simple membership to key-by
dt <- data.table(membership = setnames, d, key = "membership")
print(dt)

##    membership aa bb cc
## 1:       none  0  0  0
## 2:         aa  1  0  0
## 3:         bb  0  1  0
## 4:         bb  0  1  0
## 5:         cc  0  0  1
## 6:       aabb  1  1  0
## 7:       bbcc  0  1  1


# That might be enough for some, but the OP wants columns
# indicating a membership; so just join a matrix...
membership.map <- t(sapply(dt$membership, function(m) {
    m == levels(dt$membership)
}) * 1)
colnames(membership.map) <- levels(dt$membership)

dt <- cbind(dt, split = " ==> ", membership.map)

print(dt)

##    membership aa bb cc split none aa bb cc aabb bbcc
## 1:       none  0  0  0  ==>     1  0  0  0    0    0
## 2:         aa  1  0  0  ==>     0  1  0  0    0    0
## 3:         bb  0  1  0  ==>     0  0  1  0    0    0
## 4:         bb  0  1  0  ==>     0  0  1  0    0    0
## 5:         cc  0  0  1  ==>     0  0  0  1    0    0
## 6:       aabb  1  1  0  ==>     0  0  0  0    1    0
## 7:       bbcc  0  1  1  ==>     0  0  0  0    0    1
```

This can all be wrapped up in a quick and dirty function like so:

```
membership.table <- function(df) {

    namesets <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(d)), function(i) {
        gset(colnames(d), memberships = d[i, ])
    })

    setnames <- sapply(namesets, function(s) {
        ifelse(set_is_empty(s), "none", paste(as.character(s), collapse = ""))
    })
    names(namesets) <- setnames

    namesets <- as.set(namesets)
    setnames <- ordered(setnames, levels = names(namesets))

    dt <- data.table(membership = setnames, d, key = "membership")
    membership.map <- t(sapply(dt$membership, function(m) {
        m == levels(dt$membership)
    }) * 1)
    colnames(membership.map) <- levels(dt$membership)

    cbind(dt, split = " ==> ", membership.map)
}



mt <- membership.table(d)
identical(dt, mt)

## [1] TRUE
```

And we should now getting matching results when summarizing the membership table by-key and the membership information when creating generalized set from the original data.

```
mt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = membership, .SDcols = seq(3 + ncol(d), ncol(mt))]

##    membership none aa bb cc aabb bbcc
## 1:       none    1  0  0  0    0    0
## 2:         aa    0  1  0  0    0    0
## 3:         bb    0  0  2  0    0    0
## 4:         cc    0  0  0  1    0    0
## 5:       aabb    0  1  1  0    1    0
## 6:       bbcc    0  0  1  1    0    1


as.list(as.gset(d))

## $`3`
## (aa = 0, bb = 0, cc = 0)
## 
## $`6`
## (aa = 0, bb = 0, cc = 1)
## 
## $`1`
## (aa = 0, bb = 1, cc = 0)
## 
## $`2`
## (aa = 0, bb = 1, cc = 1)
## 
## $`4`
## (aa = 1, bb = 0, cc = 0)
## 
## $`5`
## (aa = 1, bb = 1, cc = 0)
## 
## attr(,"memberships")
## 
## 1 2 3 4 5 6 
## 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

*Notice that `bb` has a sum of `2` in the membership table, and the third item in the generalized set list (indicating `bb`) also shows 2 such sets.*

---

If this same algorithm is applied to Hong's example then the results are:

```
##     membership a b c d e f split a bc ce abd acd ade abef acdef abcdef
##  1:          a 1 0 0 0 0 0  ==>  1  0  0   0   0   0    0     0      0
##  2:         bc 0 1 1 0 0 0  ==>  0  1  0   0   0   0    0     0      0
##  3:         ce 0 0 1 0 1 0  ==>  0  0  1   0   0   0    0     0      0
##  4:        abd 1 1 0 1 0 0  ==>  0  0  0   1   0   0    0     0      0
##  5:        acd 1 0 1 1 0 0  ==>  0  0  0   0   1   0    0     0      0
##  6:        ade 1 0 0 1 1 0  ==>  0  0  0   0   0   1    0     0      0
##  7:       abef 1 1 0 0 1 1  ==>  0  0  0   0   0   0    1     0      0
##  8:      acdef 1 0 1 1 1 1  ==>  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     1      0
##  9:     abcdef 1 1 1 1 1 1  ==>  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     0      1
## 10:     abcdef 1 1 1 1 1 1  ==>  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     0      1
```

While this solution does more (like sorting and ordering) the timing isn't too horrible compared to Hong's solution; but compared to Thomas's...

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
##          hf 241.810 246.411 253.634 262.544 290.345    10
##          mt 128.105 137.931 142.966 154.244 210.276    10
##          tf   1.754   1.768   1.806   2.312   3.487    10
##  plain.gset   1.220   1.330   1.386   1.475   1.644    10
```

... both solutions are slow.  And without a doubt, if you just need to work with the sets then perhaps a little time in the sets vignette's would be worthwhile for larger memberships.

Comment: Sorry for the length... I just couldn't resist. :)

Comment: Well, of course they're slow compared to Thomas' solution, because _they're not doing the same thing._

Answer (score 0):

Since all data are binary,aka logical,  why not convert each potential combination into a number (zero thru 2^N), then, similar to @Thomas answer, convert each row in the dataframe to a single binary sequence, and then your new columns will simply be `row_value[j] == column_numeric_value[k]` (cheap pseudocode). That is, for a simple 3-column input, there are 8 possible outputs.  If `row[j]` is `1 0 1` then  `row_value[j]` is decimal "5", and `row_value[j] == column_numeric_value[5]` is true, and is false for all other columns.